# How to bind one html element to two observables?

Tags: knockout.js

I know how to bind one observable to two html elements, but how can I bind one html element to two observables with two way binding?

The html element is an input textbox.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible or advisable. What behavior do you expect when you change one of the bound observables but not the other?

Comment: What is your usecase for this? They will always have the same value, so I cant see the use case for having two. edit: You can offcourse have one event binding and one value binding with two way. But not two  value bindings. for obvious reasons

Comment: I expect both of the observables to have same values when one of them is changed. The use case I have is that I want to keep the naming consistent. I was thinking about bind the input box to a computed field and have the computed field to assign/read values two two other observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask about binding a single input field to two observables, but if your model dictates that the two observables should always be equal, that logic should be in your model, independent of your view and bindings.

To have two always equal observables, you can make one a plain observable and the other a computed observable which just reads and updates the first one.

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.first = ko.observable();
    this.second = ko.computed({
        read: this.first,
        write: this.first
    });
}
```

Then your input can be bound to either one.

EDIT: If your two properties are really just synonyms of each other, you can assign the same observable to both. This takes advantage of observables being actual objects.

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.second = this.first = ko.observable();
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep both as plain observables, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10809085/1287183

Comment: I added an even simpler method.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve this is to not actually bind both to the same HTML element, but to subscribe to the changes of one observable, setting the value of another...  If that makes sense...

In the view -

```
<div>
    <input data-bind="value: myFirstObs" />
    <span data-bind="text: myFirstObs" />
    <span data-bind="text: mySecondObs" />
</div>
```

and in the view model -

```
var myFirstObs = ko.observable();
var mySecondObs = ko.observable();

myFirstObs.subscribe(function () {
    mySecondObs(myFirstObs());
}
```

Your question is definitely a unique one...

Answer (score 1):

I would do that :

The view

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstname" />
```

The viewmodel :

```
var  vm = {
    firstname : ko.observable(),
    firstnameCopy = ko.computed({
        read : function() {return this.firstname();},
        write : function(value) { this.firstname(value);},
        owner : this
    })
};
```