# Connecting Two Knockout Variables Together Without Causing Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, binding, knockout.js, freeze

While developing code for a online calculator framework called [candy-calc](https://github.com/gbmhunter/candy-calc), I have two `ko.observables` called `calcVar1.selUnit` and `calcVar2.selUnit` which I want to connect together. By that I mean, if one changes, the other one will change, and vise versa. The way I have tried to go about this is to create two display variables calcVar1.dispSelUnit and `calcVar2.dispSelUnit`which are `ko.computed()`. These are bound to in the view, and they have different read/write functions as follows.

```
    // Modified write function  
     calcVar1.dispSelUnit = ko.computed({
        read : function(){
            console.log('Reading source var sel unit.');

            // Return as usual
            return calcVar1.selUnit();
        },
        write : function(value){
            // Write to both of them
            console.log('Writing ' + value + 'to both sel unit.');
            calcVar1.selUnit(value);
            calcVar2.selUnit(value);
        },
        owner : this
    });

    // Modified write function
    calcVar2.dispSelUnit = ko.computed({
        read : function(){
            console.log('Reading destination var sel unit.');

        // Make it equal to the source variables selected unit
            return calcVar2.selUnit();
        },
        write : function(value){
            // Write to both of them
            console.log('Writing ' + value + 'to both sel unit.');

            calcVar1.selUnit(value);
            calcVar2.selUnit(value);
        },
        owner : this
    });
}
```

So basically, the `dispSelUnits` are acting as a intermediary to the real `selUnit` values below, and on write update both `selUnit` (`ko.observables`), while on read behave as normal.

I can't see anything wrong with this logic. However, when running this, if I try and update `compVar1.dispSelUnit`, it enters a infinite loop where `compVar1.dispSelUnit` gets written then read, and then `compVar2.dispSelUnit` gets written and read, and then back again.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in those read/write functions or is this it? If not, why not just bind to the original variable immediately?

Comment: The write function is modified, it updates both variables instead of just one (see above).

Comment: But if both variables are always in sync, why not just bind to to one of those variables? Why do you have two variables in the first place? Is there another place they get updated (separately?

Comment: This "write to both `selUnit` on write to `dispSelUnit`" is how I am trying to get them in sync.

Comment: But are they separately updated somewhere else?

Comment: The 2 `dispSelVal` are bound to a view elements, so are updated when the user changes something. The behind-the-scenes `selVal` are not updated anywhere else.

Other code also accesses `dispSelVal`. I don't want to access the raw `selVal` anywhere else because they would then not be in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We also discussed this on Github (https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates/issues/17). After looking through his code, I made the following observation and suggestion.

You're getting the recursion problem because the two variables have `value` bindings to select boxes with different list of units. Although they display the same units, they are actually different objects. The `value` binding always tries to set the observable to the currently selected item in the list. But because the lists are different, this is really impossible, and the observables switch endlessly between the two values.

To fix this, you need both select boxes to reference the same objects. In `standard-resistance-finder.js`, do this:

```
var resistenceUnits = [
    new cc.unit('m\u2126', 0.001),
    new cc.unit('\u2126', 1.0),
    new cc.unit('k\u2126', 1000.0)
];

this.desiredRes = new cc.input(
    this,
    function() { return true; },
    resistenceUnits,
    0);

...

this.actualRes = new cc.output(
    this,
    ...
    resistenceUnits,
    0, 2);
```

Regarding the question of keeping two observables in sync, this question might provide some answers: [Simple, clean way to sync observables from different view models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809085/1287183)

Comment: Thanks very much, mad respect for taking the time to look through the code.